# mySQL importing a database into my database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm currently on a database and I'm trying to import another database into it.

The database is called metmessage_db_dump.sql.txt

I am using a SQL client. 
How can I import this database?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Check out the contents of the file first to determine if it is data only or contains sql statements as well. If it contains sql statements as well, then you need to determine,  if it is for mysql at all. So, pls do the first basic steps before shouting for help.

Answer (score -1):

Simply, rename you file to : metmessage_db_dump.sql and import via PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: I supposed that content from first database is the same as second.